# Blank lines after org-mode code block results in LaTeX export

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-export

**Context** I am embedding org-mode source code blocks and their results into my document and am exporting it to LaTeX. I usually wrap the output of my code into helper functions that generate formatted LaTeX code, for example equation environments or TikZ graphics.

**Question**
Unfortunately I stumbled over blank lines after the results block leading to new paragraphs in the LaTeX document. Do you see a reasonin `org-mode` for this behauvior?

**Related**
On StackOverflow there is a question regarding newline characters at the end of each python `print` invocation but this does not resolve the issue:

StackOverflow: [Print to the same line and not a new line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419984/print-to-the-same-line-and-not-a-new-line-in-python)

Modifying the `end` paramter of `print` does only insert *abc* before the newline but is not replacing it.

```
print('\\begin{equation}c+d\\end{equation}', end='abc'),
```

**Minimum working example:**

```
#+TITLE: Blank lines after source block results on export
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{lsthighlight}

* Example
In this example I would like to show that exporting a paragraph with
the embedded two source blocks
#+BEGIN_SRC python :exports results :results output latex
print('\\begin{equation}a+b\\end{equation}')
#+END_SRC
and
#+BEGIN_SRC python :exports results :results output latex
print('\\begin{equation}c+d\\end{equation}')
#+END_SRC
will result in blank lines after the result listing in the exported
LaTeX document.
```

**LaTeX export:**

```
\section{Example}
In this example I would like to show that exporting a paragraph with
the embedded two source blocks
\begin{equation}a+b\end{equation}

and
\begin{equation}c+d\end{equation}

will result in blank lines after the result listing in the exported
\LaTeX{} document.
```

[image: Exported LaTeX document]

**Instead it should be exported as follows:**

```
\section{Example}
In this example I would like to show that exporting a paragraph with
the embedded two source blocks
\begin{equation}a+b\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}c+d\end{equation}
will result in blank lines after the result listing in the exported
\LaTeX{} document.
```

[image: Expected LaTeX document]

I really have no idea where to look for this issue. That's why I have the hope that you can help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: Your MWE produced different results for me via `org-latex-export-as-latex`, do you have a variable set somewhere that asserts that equations must be exported?  They are simply ignored at export time on my system.

Comment: OK, I can reproduce the behavior you described if I evaluate: `(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages '((python . t)))  (setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be specific to python, I can reproduce the same behavior with an `emacs-lisp :exports results :results value latex` block containing `(print "foo")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking under the hood of org-mode, here's what I'd suggest.

Comment out [Line 1987](http://orgmode.org/w/org-mode.git?p=org-mode.git;a=blob;f=lisp/ob-core.el;h=6821b6dfc970675e0260e5eecc87d0ca519faa12;hb=HEAD#l1987) in the current/latest version `ob-core.el`, evaluate, test, and if you like what you see, don't forget to byte compile.

If you are using a different version of Org, the line is part of the function `org-babel-where-is-src-block-result`, and it reads as follows:

```el
(unless beg (insert "\n") (backward-char))
```

If you want a cleaner solution, there is probably another function you could advise. But I'll leave you to find that; now you know where the newline comes from.

#### method

Maybe useful for you to know how I went about it.  I dug into the export routines, starting with `org-latex-export-as-latex`, until I found the `ob-core.el` file. There are lots of newlines introduced there.  To pinpoint which was responsible, I replaced each `"\n"` with some `"N\n"` (where `N` is a counting number) then reran the export.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you very much! Replacing ´"\n"´ by ´""´ resolves the issue! :) :)

Comment: I will try to improve my debugging capabilities, such that I can find it myself next time. Thank you again :)